# Wrapping each word and each letter within each word jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Imagine you have string of text. Every letter in that string should get a random font from an array.

To do this, i wrapped all letters within a `span` and randomized that font-family.

Problem with this approach is word-wrap. Now, when a sentence breaks, i have a letter-wrap where individual letter break to next line.

To fix this i want to also wrap each word in a span and apply `word-wrap` on that span.

So every individual word should have span. Every individual letter within that word should also get a span.

I could really use some help, below example outputs all letters * words. How to fix this?

```
var elem = $('.curiosa-type');

    elem.each(function( i ) {

        var currentElem = $(this);
        var words = currentElem.text().split(" ");
        var fonts = ['&#39Times&#39', '&#39Arial&#39'];
        currentElem.empty();

        $.each(words, function (i, el) {


            currentElem.append('<span class="word">' + el + '</span>');

            var characters = currentElem.text().split("");

            console.log(characters);

                $.each(characters, function (i, el) {

                    var rand = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];

                    currentElem.append("<span style='font-family:" + rand + "'>" + el + "</span");
                    // check 4 white space
                    if(el.indexOf(' ') >= 0){
                        //console.log(el);
                        currentElem.append('<span class="spacer"></span>');

                    }

                });


        });





    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes on your code, you was emptying **currentElem** and then reading it's text(was returning empty, of course). I'm building the word container(div) before appending it into the DOM and then append it all to the DOM when it's done.

```
var elem = $('.curiosa-type');
elem.each(function( i ) {
    var currentElem = $(this);
    var words = currentElem.text().split(" ");
    var fonts = ['&#39Times&#39', '&#39Arial&#39'];
    currentElem.empty();
    $.each(words, function (i, el) {
        console.log(words);
        // currentElem.append('<span class="word">' + el + '</span>'); //doesnt need it
        var characters = el.split('');
        var $div = $('<div>'); // create jQuery Element on fly so we can append to it even when it isn't in the DOM yet
        console.log(characters);
        $.each(characters, function (i, el) {
            var rand = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
            $div.append("<span style='font-family:" + rand + "'>" + el + "</span");
            // check 4 white space
            if(el.indexOf(' ') >= 0){
                $div.append('<span class="spacer"></span>');
            }
        });
        currentElem.append($div); // append our jQuery Element o the current ".curiosa-type" element
    });
});
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made a different fiddle but I guess if it works for you it would be easier part to implement it in your code.

I made an array with fonts and splitting each word into a span with word-wrap. With that being done each word is getting a random generated font and words can break into a new lines if there is not enough space.

I don't see a reason for each letter to be in a unique span - that loads a lot of html for no apparent reason.

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
var fonts = ['courier','sans-serif', 'verdana'];
var color = ['red','green', 'blue'];
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
  var rand_font = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random() * fonts.length)];
    var rand_color = color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)];
    $("p").append($("<span style=\"color: "+rand_color+"; font-family:'"+rand_font+"'\">"+v+"</span>"));
});
```

```css
span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Mitko! Nice and short. I'm curios, how would you go and have all individual letters a different font without wrapping them into some html node?

Comment: @WIWIWWIISpitFire Do you need them to be in different fonts? I understood that you need different font for the words and span for the letters so they fall on new line. 

I don't think of other way to have different font for each letter unless wrapping them in spans.